# Symfony ApiPlatform 3.0.6 POST route Abstract Item normalizer error

Tags: api-platform.com, php-8.1, symfony6

I am in the middle of upgrading a project from API 2.7 to API 3.0 and have trouble with this
[POST route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jBI.png)

This is my request body:

```
[
  {
    "name": "firstName",
    "width": "10%",
    "priority": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "lastName",
    "width": "10%",
    "priority": 1
  }
]
```

The error output is:

```
 "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
 "@type": "hydra:Error",
 "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
 "hydra:description": "ApiPlatform\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer::canAccessAttributePostDenormalize(): Argument #3 ($attribute) must be of type string, int given
```

I had a similar issue on another route and defining `uriVariables`  solved it, but that did not work this time.

Comment: I'm not sure about you exactly want, what :)), but for this step you can use `deserialize: false` .

Comment: yeah you were right , kinda , I setted allow extra attributes to false in normalozation context  and deserialize to false , and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem turned out to be that I was sending a plain array without a key prefix, *not* a property which was incorrect.

```php
$client->request('PUT',  'some-url', [
    'body' => json_encode(['a', 'b', 'c'])
]);
```

That means the keys of the array are indexed (eg the [0], [1], ...), which seems to be the int from the "got int, expected string". For us the solution was to give it a key

```php
$client->request('PUT',  'some-url', [
    'body' => json_encode(['example' => ['a', 'b', 'c']])
]);
```

This ment we had to update the code too, to also use that key, but that was a minimal amount of work.